# modify default values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to modify default values for a column?

```
create table customers1 (
    id int, 
    name varchar(20), 
    age int, 
    salary decimal(18,2) constraint df_constraint default 5000.00, 
    address varchar(20) )
```

now i want to be change default salary values to 7000.00

Comment: Salary as decimal(18,2)?!? Hire me!

Comment: @jarlh might not be in dollars...

Comment: @TabAlleman, that's still quite a lot of Yen.  I'd only be disappointed with a salary on that scale if it was in [Zimbabwean Third Dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwean_dollar#Devaluation_of_the_third_dollar)...

Comment: Oh but wait, this is the `Customers` salary.   I guess they sell yachts?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
ALTER TABLE customers1 ADD CONSTRAINT NameYourConstraint DEFAULT ((7000.00))  FOR [Salary]
```

Then drop the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

When you create table you can add Constraints. Adding a default, constraints by name.
ADD CONSTRAINT SalaryConstraint DEFAULT ((5000.00))  FOR [Salary]

This script alters table to add value, but it won't effect old data already there
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER101 ADD CONSTRAINT SalaryConstraint DEFAULT ((5000.00))  FOR [Salary]

Dropping Constraing is 
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER101  DROP CONSTRAINT SalaryConstraint